# Vertical Scroll View on Windows using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, scrollview

I am using jQuery 1.1 plus PhoneGap. I have been trying to implement a vertical scroll with rows (basically a List view with custom cells) using jQuery Mobile for Windows Mobile. I have been searching it on every forum I could get to, but haven't found any suitable tut to do so.

It is working on iOS and Android, but due to some reason, it fails to work on Windows Mobile.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The scrolling behaviour in jQuery Mobile relies on CSS 3D transforms to emulate mobile-style browsing. The use of transforms ensures that the rendered content is placed in a new 'layer' which can be hardware accelerated on browsers that support this.

Unfortunately the Windows Phone browser does not support 3D transforms so none of this will work!

The jQuery Mobile team, working with Microsoft, have created [a special Metro theme](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/04/introducing-the-jquery-mobile-metro-theme/) that you might want to try.